# Mongoid: support for 'saved_change_to_attribute' and 'attribute_before_last_save'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

`attribute_changed?` and `attribute_was` ActiveRecord methods will be deprecated inside of after_(create|update|save) callbacks [source](http://blog.toshima.ru/2017/04/06/saved-change-to-attribute.html)

Does Mongoid support mettods `saved_change_to_attribute?` and `attribute_before_last_save` to maintain consistency ?